# How do you scale your applications and datastores horizontally using AppHarbor and DB add-ons

Tags: amazon-web-services, appharbor, mlab, horizontal-scaling

If you're talking directly to AWS then you have a few options, but essentially you'd do the following to scale your apps:

### Scaling App Servers on EC2

You'd use a combination of CloudWatch and the EC2 services to look at perf metrics, and based on that spin up and spin down EC2 app instances as you'd see fit.

### Scaling SQL and NoSQL dbs

This is a bit different depending on the DB, but [AWS abstracts a lot from you](http://vimeo.com/52252773), so if you're using their services there are ways to scale horizontally programatically with DBs.

### AppHarbor Questions

- Appharbor introduces the notion of workers. Are workers like multiple instances, and do they get automatically load balanced?
- Can I add/remove workers programatically? If so, based on what metrics?
- If you're using an add-on, say MongoLab for simplicity sake, do you have to manage your sharding manually by have multiple MongoLab dbs, or do add-on providers provide that abstraction for you?
- Essentially, what is the Horizontal Scaling story for AppHarbor?